# What is our time-size in spacetime? Are we spaghetti or flat blobs?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime

In special and general relativity time is treated as a dimension ($ict$, being $t$ a real number). Computations usually revolve around describing world lines, and events (crossings of world lines).

But objects can't physically be time-lines. Future unfolds through projections of quantum states, so the lines would have to have tips. Thinking about tips leaving a literal energy-trails in the time direction sounds bad (You leave a pebble in space for a day, so now you have a light-day*mc more energy in your universe, leaving a longer and longer trail every day)

Lets take a human as an example. An approximation where a set of points are roughly always moving together, are not very much apart (measured in $ct$), are subjected always roughly to the same gravitational potential. The watch on your left hand is usually always ticks the same way as the watch on your right hand. So humans are essentially flat blobs flying through time. How bad is this approximation?

If we're flat blobs, what is our size in the time dimension? Planck's constant/momentum-uncertainty?

A flat-blob also means there's no way you could meet your younger self by using a time machine (unless doing some cloning). Because you're something with near-zero time-size, you can't reach back to a younger-self because you're not a line in time.

Answer (score 6):

We are very much not flat blobs. The spaghetti is much closer. We are on average about 70 light-years long in the time direction.

So even spaghetti does not really convey the concept of how anisotropic we are. A spaghetti noodle is roughly 1 mm diameter and 300 mm long. For a 6’ human a spaghetti-proportional length is 1800’ which would correspond to a length in the time dimension of only 1.8 microseconds. So we are more like the longest spool of the finest gossamer thread imaginable.

Comment: I prefer to measure myself in feet, and measure time in "light-nanoseconds", so I am neither spaghetti nor a blob!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unusual_units_of_measurement#Light-nanosecond

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldabra_giant_tortoise, one giant tortoise in the Kolkata Zoo in India was found to be about 255 light-years long in the time direction. I don't know how credible that is, but there are several cases of giant tortoises being well over 150 light-years long.

Comment: You can't be a world line. Future unfolds through projections of quantum states onto bases (measurements), outcome is non-deterministic. Therefore your line wound have to have a tip where future unfolds. Also you definitely don't leave a line in the past (trail of energy) because it would violate conservation of energy. Imagine your future unfolds another 1 light-minute, you leave a trail, therefore the 4 dimensional spacetime now has 1 light-minute long spaghetti worth of energy more in it.

Comment: @JohnDeeDoe that is a statement of the philosophical concept of presentism. You are contrasting it with the philosophical concept of eternalism. Both are philosophical concepts that are completely compatible with experiment and current theory. Your “you can’t” and “definitely don’t” statements are incorrect. Both philosophical views are perfectly compatible with modern science.

Comment: The fact that most of the matter in our body is replaced with new atoms after a few years really ruins this answer.

Answer (score -2):

Although in the geometric picture of general relativity time is pictured as a dimension this is not how Einstein viewed the matter. He was against interpreting physics in a purely geometric fashion which began with Minkowski interpreting special relativity with a Lorentz metric. In fact, he saw general relativity as the unification of inertia and gravitation.

Comment: This doesn't at all seem relevant to the question asked by OP.

Comment: @Eletie: He said "in special and general relativity time is trested as a dimension." I'm pointing out that this is not how Einstein thought about it.

Comment: @Eletie: I'm disputing some of his premises.

Comment: Then perhaps this should be a comment, not an answer. Modern GR is done on a four-dimensional Lorentzian manifold representing spacetime (which isn't controversial).

Comment: @Eletie: I know that, I also know that Einstein didn't think that way from an article I read in a journal devoted to the history of physics. I think he would be a little dismayed at the characterisation of GR as simply geometry of a certain kind. As I've pointed out in my answer he saw GR as a unification of inertia and gravity, both of which are physical concepts.

Comment: Einstein may initially have resisted the geometric interpretation of relativity, but he fully embraced it later. In fact the general theory of relativity is completely expressed in geometric terms and with time treated as a dimension.

Comment: @Eric Smith: I don't think this is quite correct.  The time that I'm referring to is well after he had formulated GR. Although he was appreciative of the geometry, he nonetheless emphasised physical concepts.

Comment: The Einstein field equations are geometric and 4 dimensional, treating time as a coordinate on a similar footing to the space coordinates. There's no question about that, just look at them! I do recall reading that Einstein was initially resistant to Minkowski's 4 dimensional interpretation of relativity, but that was obviously before he formulated GR.

Comment: @Eric Smith: I Know about the geometric definition of Einsteinian gravity including it's definition via the Einstein-Hilbert action using the metric and the Palatini action via the connection. Einstein wasn't just initially resistant to the formulation of Special Relativity as a kind of geometry as formulated by Minkowski, but also the later reformulation of GR as just as you did. There is a letter that Einstein wrote to a doctoral student, I forget to whom, where he resists thinking of the equation of inertial motion geodesically as advocated by the student & emphasised that he saw it as ...

Comment: @Eric Smith: ... the unification of inertia and gravity.

Comment: Einstein's original papers are available online. In his 1915 paper "Formal Foundation of the General Theory of Relativity" ( https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/56 ) Einstein writes:

"From a mathematical point of view, the movement of a point, therefore, corresponds [14] to a geodesic line in a four-dimensional manifold." This is from his original paper on GR, and shows he was thinking geometrically then (read the rest of the paper for plenty of other examples).

Comment: @Eric Smith: He wrote, "from a *mathematical point of view*", which is exactly what is under consideration there. He doesn't say, from a *physical point of view*, which is what I am talking about amd which he also talks about later. Given that the apparatus of the absolute differential geometry or tensor calculus had to be learnt by physicists from mathematicians, it's not surprising that he knows the mathematical motivation and pov.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah: In your original answer you wrote: "Although in the geometric picture of general relativity time is pictured as a dimension this is not how Einstein viewed the matter." We can keep quibbling forever, but throughout the 1915 paper I linked to Einstein treats time as a coordinate. I invite you to post a link to any writing of Einstein's after 1914 in which he rejects this way of handling space and time.

Comment: @Eric Smith: Have a look at [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1355219813000695) article, titled *Why Einstein did not believe that GR geometrises gravity*, published in the journal, *The History & Philosophy of Modern Physics* and where they quote Einstein saying (see section 2) "It is wrong to see Geometrisation as something essential, it is only a kind of a crutch to finding numerical laws". This was in 1926, a full decade after Einstein came up with GR and so represents his mature opinion.